# Is it possible to have a button inside settings Bundle - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need a button inside a settings bundle like Twitter application.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the question some more.

Comment: I wish I could ask such questions and get the exact answer I need...

Comment: I need to place a button inside a setting like twitter app.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: please refer image which I added

Comment: Not possible for normal app store apps.  If you're writing jailbreak apps, then you can do so with Preference Bundles.

Comment: I can see some apps from app store had this kind of settings

Comment: Twitter is special.  You're not Twitter, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nate that I know Twitter is special. I ask the solution not comparision

Comment: I know what you're asking.  I can read.  Just because you want a solution, doesn't mean there is one.  Twitter worked with Apple on features built-in to iOS.  As such, they've been allowed to use private APIs.  You are not allowed to do so.

Comment: @Nate can I use http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this this help you to create a custom settings

http://www.inappsettingskit.com/

Answer (score 0):

From the comments & discussion I guess you want simply your app name into settings in iPhone.

If I'm not wrong and if you want to implement like what I understood, You need to Localize Your App . Please folllow the given url: [Localize iPhone application](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/15/localize-iphone-application-name.html)

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: no I need a link button inside setting that should open a browser

Comment: @Foram: I am sure that this is not correct. Poster doesnt want to add "Setting.Bundle" to his app. Rather he want to add installation button under "Settings App" in iPhone which is provided for device, network settings and notification settings. I would like you to edit and correct your answer, if you know the solution.